# ArcScene vs Sketch up

Tags: arcscene, sketchup

I am familiar with ArcMap but I have had not really used ArcScene. (I'm on 9.4) I am want to create a house model to remodel and I am wondering if it would be easier to do in ArcScene or Google Sketchup?

In addition, I'm also wondering if I could create a 3D shapefile in ArcMap & then add to ArcScene? I did not see any options to dispaly a 3D shapefile in ArcScene.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: 9.4? it did exist for a brief beta but it is either 9.3 or 10 now.

Comment: For 3D building creation use Sketchup as Radar mentions.

Comment: I think a more relevant question would be [CityEngine](http://www.esri.com/software/cityengine/index.html) vs Sketchup.

Comment: CityEngine for a city, but not a single house model.

Comment: SketchUp without a doubt. ArcScene is not suited for this type of work.

Answer (score 7):

Have you ever created a building model using ArcMap? I'm confused as to why you would choose any of the ArcGIS products for this application, as it was designed for geographic data, not 3D modelling of structures.

Google Sketchup is very easy to learn and there are some very good tutorials on their [website](http://sketchup.google.com/intl/en/training/index.html) and on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=google%20sketchup%20&oq=google%20sktch&aq=0s&aqi=g-s10&aql=&gs_sm=c&gs_upl=2361l3853l0l5219l12l8l0l0l0l0l207l995l1.6.1l8l0) - I'd highly recommend it and would steer clear of ESRI products for tasks outside of geographic data - especially ArcScene, which can be touchy at the best of times.

Answer (score 1):

For a single house model, you are better off using Sketchup.  But if you want to know about ArcScene and Sketchup in workflow, there are a couple of posts which both point to the same YouTube videos.

ESRI's 3D blog: http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/3dgis/archive/2010/10/25/ArcGIS-to-SketchUp-and-back.aspx

Official Sketchup blog: http://sketchupdate.blogspot.com/2010/10/arcgis-10-and-sketchup-8.html

Answer (score 0):

I use sketch up for all of the models I build for my portfolio of properties.  It is fantastic to prepare models you can put in front of planners in order to best approximate a design they will like:

Without getting too into detail.  It allows you to take a laptop to a planning meeting, and in real time, remove detail that is suggested wouldn't get through planning, and adding to it detail that would.  Once you've agreed with the planners it's a good plan, you can then present it to your architects knowing it's, effectively, a once drawn solution.  Saves money and time.

I have no idea why anyone would want to use an ArcGIS product for this and, trust me, being the evangelical GI pro I am, i would have found a use for it by now if I could ahve done ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the 3D model in Sketchup. Export it as Collada format (.dae). Create a multipatch file in ArcScene and import the building. Now you can visualize the 3D model created in Sketchup using arcscene